# Multiple Declaration of Constructor C++

Tags: c++, declaration

I'm getting errors for my class called Point3D and I really don't understand why.

Here is my header:

```
#ifndef POINT3D_H
#define POINT3D_H

using namespace std;
class Point3D {

public:
    Point3D(float x, float y, float z);
    float operator[] (const int i);
private:
    float xyz[3];

};

#endif
```

And here is the cpp file:

```
#include "point3d.h"

Point3D::Point3D(float x, float y, float z){
    xyz[0] = x;
    xyz[1] = y;
    xyz[2] = z;
}

float Point3D::operator[](int i )
{

    if(i == 0){
        return xyz[0];
    }
    else if(i == 1){
        return xyz[1];
    }
    else if(i == 2){
        return xyz[2];
    }

    return -1;

}
```

There are the complier errors:

```
/tmp/ccyDEfcW.o: In function `Point3D::Point3D(float, float, float)':
vector3d.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Point3D::Point3D(float, float, float)'
/tmp/ccqDasr3.o:point3d.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccyDEfcW.o: In function `Point3D::Point3D(float, float, float)':
vector3d.cc:(.text+0x10): multiple definition of `Point3D::Point3D(float, float, float)'
/tmp/ccqDasr3.o:point3d.cc:(.text+0x10): first defined here
/tmp/ccyDEfcW.o: In function `Point3D::operator[](int)':
vector3d.cc:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `Point3D::operator[](int)'
/tmp/ccqDasr3.o:point3d.cc:(.text+0x20): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You should remove `using namespace std;` from your header file. It's almost universally a bad idea and you are not even using anything from the `std` namespace in any case.

Comment: This code is perfectly valid. Either you have errors in a different piece of code, or you forgot to include something in the post.

Comment: What's the error?  What line does it indicate?

Comment: How are you creating object of Point3D class, and what exact error you are getting?

Comment: "I'm getting errors for my class" is not specific enough to give a good answer

Comment: Sorry, I added the compiler errors just now

Comment: "vector3d.cc".. Are you `include`-ing the .cpp file ?

Comment: All I can see the difference in declaration of 'float operator[] (const int i);'
 and definition you have missed const parameter.

Comment: thanks, that was the problem. it was a garbage file in the directory... i will vote to delete this post as i doubt it will help anyone

Comment: @MarsRover: ... which makes no difference because it's still the same function signature.

Comment: By the way, your access operator implementation is just great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have different declaration in the header:

```
float operator[] (const int i);
```

and definition in .cpp:

```
float Point3D::operator[](int i )
```

Make both of them with the same parameter

```
const int i
```

2) Look at vector3d.cc (and please share it here),
You probably have defined Point3D code twice.

Comment: How would changing a parameter of a member function help to get rid of "multiply definition of constructor" errors?

Comment: This is not an error.  Top level const qualifiers(or lack thereof) in a declaration are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: You're right, colleagues, this is not a error. And the code is valid, I've compiled it without errors. @Aneem should provide more information.